# Unable to knock to Areca ARC-6020

Tags: raid

Several months ago we got a RAID Areca ARC 6020, without any cables nor instructions on how to set it up. This device is a real dinosaur but we would like to make it workable as a storage array for our team.

I tried to ping it over the network but I did not succeed with that. I don't even know what IP address it has. I am not a geek in system networking who is able to configure it and would appreciate any instructions on how to compel this heap of iron to begin to work.

The box, that contains the ARC, only has LAN and a strange port with many contacts that looks like SCSI but longer.

Answer (score 0):

There's not that much information online about this box but it appears to be a simple SCSI to SATA converter tied to a SATA enclosure of some sort. Presumably this was just to allow some old SCSI-only machine to access cheapo SATA drives for some reason. The wide connector will probably be one form of SCSI connector but I doubt the 'LAN port' is that, it's probably something else entirely just using an RJ45 socket.

I'd avoid using it, especially given your lack of knowledge in this area. If you're dead-set on using it I'd just be tempted to rip out the disks and use them in some kind or normal SATA box that *can* attach to whatever server you want it to worth with.

You've provided very little information in your question so this is the best we'll be able to do, also what the hell does "Unable to knock to" mean? It means nothing in English at all.

Answer (score 0):

The manual can be found on manualslib, [Areca ARC-6020 Series User Manual (187 pages)](https://www.manualslib.com/products/Areca-Arc-6020-Series-5887851.html).

From page 33 of said manual,

> [image: Backside of ARC-5030 and ARC-6020]

So the long connector, to which you refer, is probably a *SATA Host Input/Output Channel Adapter Port*.

However, there is another version, with external SATA/Firewire/USB connections, a COM port and a RJ-45, that has a rear that looks like this:

[image: ARC-6020 rear view]

For completeness the front view looks like this:

[image: ARC-6020 front view]

You should be able to determine the IP address from the LCD display on the front, as, by default, that is what is displayed:

[image: Front panel LCD display showing IP address]